# coldfusion cfftp timeout

Tags: coldfusion, timeout, cfftp

I need to FTP a file to a server and the file is about 30 MB, in my code, I have defined the timeout:

```
cfsetting requesttimeout="3000"
```

and

```
cfftp action="open" connection="objConnection" timeout="3000" .......
```

But it still timeout when running.

I am using CF8

Any idea are welcomed, thanks in advance.

This is what I got: An error occurred during the FTP putfile operation. | Error: putfile operation exceeded timeout.

Comment: 3000 seconds = 50 minutes. That means less than 10K/s transfer rate. Are you sure its really a timeout issue?

Comment: Hi Mitch, it takes me about 30mins to FTP the whole file, drag and drop, and it works fine.

Comment: and how is that in conflict with my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ColdFusion (plus cumulative update) do you have?

There were reports of a bogus timeout error (even though operation completes) in previous CU's.

Try placing the timeout parameter in the getfile (or whatever the equivalent sendfile is) operation (instead of the open operation as the CFML Reference instructs)

Comment: Hi Mitch, I add the timeout parameter in the putfile operation and it works. Thanks for that.I google this issue before and found some infomation, here is an example: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1337-My-First-ColdFusion-8-CFFTP-Experience-Rocky-But-Triumphant.htm. The author didn't mention we have to put the timeout in putfile action.